# How can one inject initialization steps into a workflow service?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

I am writing a WF4 service and I need to perform some initialization (e.g. initializing log4net).  In a normal service, I would just modify global.asax but there is no such file in the WF4 service.  Where then do I place this initialization?

This must be a simple matter but I cannot find any answers here on SO or elsewhere so far.  Sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases I'd just use a custom activity at the very beginning of the workflow that does the initialization.

For more elaborate scenarios you can take a look at [`System.ServiceModel.Activities.Activation.WorkflowServiceHostFactory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activities.activation.workflowservicehostfactory(v=vs.110).aspx).

A blog post with a usage example can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/27/how-to-create-a-wf4-workflowservicehostfactory-for-appfabric-auto-start.aspx

Comment: Yeah,  I found this answer myself a couple months ago.  One caution:  If one is using C# expressions in the workflow, overriding the `WorkflowServiceHostFactory` will require that you pre-compile your C# expressions (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591618%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  If you do not, you get a very unhelpful, confusing error message.